# How to replace NaN values of a DataFrame column with existing column values?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Sample dataframe df :

```
  EateryItem
0 Burger
1 pizza
2 Donut
3 NaN
4 NaN
5 NaN
6  .
.  .
.  .
15 NaN
```

To get the preceding item filled i found solution as

```
df.bfill().ffill()
```

My expected result is filling NaN with existing column values(Not necessarily same order,may be in random too):

```
EateryItem
0 Burger
1 pizza
2 Donut
3 Burger
4 pizza
5 Donut
6 Burger
7 pizza
8 Donut
9 Burger
10 pizza
11 Donut
.   .
.   .
```

Comment: random from the existing values right?

Comment: yeah mate(pizza,burger,donut)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to get a random sample of items from `EateryItem`

```py
values_to_fill = df['EateryItem']\
                .dropna()\
                .sample(n=df['EateryItem'].isna().sum(), random_state=1,replace=True)

df.loc[df['EateryItem'].isna(), 'EateryItem'] = values_to_fill.to_numpy()
```

```
    EateryItem
0   Burger
1   pizza
2   Donut
3   pizza
4   Burger
5   Burger
6   pizza
...
```

## Edit

`dropna` returns `pandas.core.series.Series` that contains only valid values:

```py
df['EateryItem'].dropna()
# 0    Burger
# 1     pizza
# 2     Donut
# Name: EateryItem, dtype: object
```

From those values I want to get a random sample, so I use `.sample`:

```py
df['EateryItem'].dropna()\
                .sample(n=df['EateryItem'].isna().sum(), random_state=1,replace=True)

# 1     pizza
# 0    Burger
# 0    Burger
# 1     pizza
# Name: EateryItem, dtype: object
```

`n` here is a number of items to return. In this case, I need a number that is equal to the sum of all missing values, hence `.isna().sum()`:

```py
df['EateryItem'].isna().sum()
# 4
```

`random_state=1` is a seed and was added for reproducibility (could be ommited).

`replace` specifies whether sample with or without replacement. If it were `False`, as per default, an error would raise: `ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'`

using `.to_numpy` converts values of a `Series` to an array, giving:

```py
values_to_fill.to_numpy()

# array(['pizza', 'Burger', 'Burger', 'pizza'], dtype=object)
```

---

Now that I have an array with items, I could use them to fill missing values from original `Series`.

```py
df.loc[df['EateryItem'].isna(), 'EateryItem'] = values_to_fill.to_numpy()
```

using `.isna` with `.loc`, I filtered rows with missing values:

```py
df.loc[df['EateryItem'].isna()]

#   EateryItem
# 3 NaN
# 4 NaN
# 5 NaN
# 6 NaN
```

After that I specified that I want to replace missing values from above with an array `values_to_fill.to_numpy()`: `... , 'EateryItem'] = values_to_fill.to_numpy()`.

Comment: I understood the pieces of the code but not able to put it together as you did.....

Comment: Wow, super thanks this makes me understand every bit mate!!

Answer (score 1):

You  can:
Create a random array by [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) from the non `NaN` elements to the length of `NaN` elements : `int(df.EateryItem.isna().sum())` , then using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) , filter the `NaN` elements and assign this array

```
s=np.random.choice(df.EateryItem.dropna(),int(df.EateryItem.isna().sum()))
df.loc[df.EateryItem.isna(),'EateryItem']=s
print(df)
```

---

```
  EateryItem
0     Burger
1      pizza
2      Donut
3      pizza
4      Donut
5      Donut
.....
....
```

Comment: @Codenewbie updated, you can also use `replace=False` , `s=np.random.choice(df.EateryItem.dropna(),int(df.EateryItem.isna().sum()),replace=False)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this,

```
s = df.item.dropna().unique().tolist()
m = df.item.isnull()
temp = s*int(len(df)/len(s))
temp = temp[:len(df[m])]
df.loc[m, 'item'] = temp
```

O/P:

```
      item
0   burger
1    pizza
2    donut
3   burger
4    pizza
5    donut
6   burger
7    pizza
8    donut
9   burger
10   pizza
11   donut
12  burger
13   pizza
14   donut
```

Note: this will maintain order too :)

Comment: sorry ,I am learning pandas and I want to understand and learn every bit of code here, I understood that s=['burger','pizza','donut']  , m has True for all NaN, temp=['burger','pizza','donut''burger','pizza','donut''burger','pizza','donut'], and I didn't understand next part , make me correct if what I have assumed is wrong....thanks

Comment: `s` contains only valid elements. `m` contains boolean series where True if that row is NaN. `temp` contains repeated values of valid elements (s). Now temp holds all values for `item`, but we need only for NaN values. So it slices required values. Now we place whatever the values in temp will be hold by NaN in `item`. I hope you are cleared now. I suggest you to run each line one by one and check intermediate result. Happy Coding :)